# Prevent a weakly assigned variable from being dealloc'ed without creating a retain cycle

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, nsnotificationcenter

I have an odd case involving ARC, NSNotificationCenter and a block. The following is a simplified example of the code. From testing it seems that the memory management of  `didSaveObserver` is performing as desired, i.e. it is not creating a retain cycle and it is not being `nil`ed before `removeObserver:`.

However, my understanding of ARC makes me think that this is just a fluke/quirk and ARC could `nil` `didSaveObserver` before `removeObserver:`. Seeing as `didSaveObserver` is never retained (the only assignment is to a `weak` variable), then ARC could/(should?) instantly dealloc it.

Have I understood the ARC rules correctly? If so then how do I ensure that the `didSaveObserver` is retained so that it can be unobserved but not create a retain cycle?

```
self.willSaveObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

    id preSaveState = ...; //Store some interesting state about a Core Data object (the details aren't significant to this question).

    __weak __block id didSaveObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    //Unobserve the did save block. This is the tricky bit! didSaveObserver must be __weak to avoid a retain cycle, but doing so also means that the block may be dealloced before it can be unobsered.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:didSaveObserver];        

        id postSaveState = ...;
        //Perform work that uses pre & post save states.
    }];
}];
```

**More details:**

If `__weak` is not added (so defaults to `__strong`) Instruments reports that there's a retain cycle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comment in NSNotification.h that explains why `didSaveObserver` isn't dealloced in this particular case:

```
// The return value is retained by the system, and should be held onto by the caller in
// order to remove the observer with removeObserver: later, to stop observation.
```

Of course, that only explains this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you think it would create a retain cycle? The block would retain `didSaveObserver`, yes. Would `didSaveObserver` retain the block? Nothing is documented about the returned observer object other than it can be used in `removeObserver:` to remove the added observation. It is possible that it somehow retains the block or is the block itself, in which case it would create a retain cycle. If you want to be safe, yes, you could use `weak` to refer to the observer in the block.

> Seeing as didSaveObserver is never retained (the only assignment is to
>   a weak variable), then ARC could/(should?) instantly dealloc it.

Unless it is retained by the notification center before returning to you.

Comment: I think it creates a retain cycle because Instruments says that it does. I've updated the question.